# HTML, CSS how to place a list alogside a group of images?

Tags: html, css, list

so i have to write a list alogside these images in the code i wrote:

```
<div class="asideContent">
    <ul> 
        <li>  <p> </p> </li> 
        <li>  <p></p> </li>          
        <li>  <p>  </p> </li> 
    </ul>
    <div class = "imageAside">
        <img class=""src=img/Dedede.jpg alt="">
    </div>
    <div class = "imageAside">
        <img class=""src=img/tournament.jpg alt="">
    </div>
    <div class = "imageAside">
        <img class=""src=img/Secret.jpg alt="">   
    </div>

</div>
```

biggest problem i have with it, is that the list either over or under the images. i need it to stick to the right. using float in css doesn't seem to be working well.

Comment: Have you tried to use CSS `float`?

Comment: yes i floated the list to right, nothing productive

Comment: How exactly did you float the list? Simply adding the CSS rule `ul { float: right; }` does it for me, as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` and `margin-left`, don't use `float` always make more complex. Try this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.asideContent {
 display: flex;
 margin-left: auto;
}

.asideImage {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="asideContent">
    <ul> 
        <li>  <p> hey </p> </li> 
        <li>  <p> hey !</p> </li>          
        <li>  <p>  hey 3</p> </li> 
    </ul>
    <div class="asideImage">
        <div class = "imageAside">
          <img class=""src=img/Dedede.jpg alt="">
        </div>
        <div class = "imageAside">
            <img class=""src=img/tournament.jpg alt="">
        </div>
        <div class = "imageAside">
            <img class=""src=img/Secret.jpg alt="">   
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You also can play with flex and margin auto to include this of more elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `float: left` for images:

```css
.imagesAside {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="asideContent">
  <div class="imagesAside">
      <div class = "imageAside">
          <img class=""src=img/Dedede.jpg alt="">
      </div>
      <div class = "imageAside">
          <img class=""src=img/tournament.jpg alt="">
      </div>
      <div class = "imageAside">
          <img class=""src=img/Secret.jpg alt="">   
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul> 
        <li>  <p>h</p> </li> 
        <li>  <p>h</p> </li>          
        <li>  <p>h</p> </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```